# Equivalence between elements of different sets - how to formally define the "equivalence classes"?

Tags: definition, equivalence-relations

What would be a good formal definition for the set $\mathcal T$ constructed below? I will try and give a simple example.

Consider the set $[\;n\;]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, as well the family $\mathcal{C}$ of all subsets of cardinality 3 of $[\;n\;]$: $$\mathcal{C}=\{\{1,2,3\}, \{1,2,4\}, \ldots, \{n-2,n-1,n\}\}.$$
Obviously, every set $C \in \mathcal{C}$ has the same structure - it consists of three elements, $C=\{c^{C}_{1},c^{C}_{2},c^{C}_{3}\}$ with $c^{C}_{1}<c^{C}_{2}<c^{C}_{3}$ - or in other words, every set $C \in \mathcal{C}$ has a smallest, a second-smallest and a largest element.

I would now like to define a set $\mathcal{T}=\{t_{1},t_{2},t_{3}\}$ which generalizes the sets $C\in \mathcal{C}$ in the following sense: $t_{1}$ is a symbol representing the smallest element of a three-element set,  $t_{2}$ represents the second-smallest element, and $t_{3}$ represents the largest element. (The intention is to view $\mathcal{T}$ as a poset and use its properties to draw conclusions about $\mathcal{C}$, but that is irrelevant for the current question.)

One possible way of defining $\mathcal{T}$ might be to construct its elements as equivalence classes in the following way:

---

**Definition Ver. 1:** Consider a multiset $$D=\bigcup_{C\in\mathcal{C}}\bigcup_{j=1}^{3}\left\{ c_{j}^{C}\right\}$$
and the following equivalence relation $\sim$ defined on $D$:
$$c_{j_{1}}^{C_{1}}\sim c_{j_{2}}^{C_{2}}\Longleftrightarrow j_{1}=j_{2}.$$
We define the set $\mathcal{T}$ as $\mathcal{T}=D/\sim$ and its elements as the equivalence classes $t_{j}=\left[c_{j}^{C}\right]$.

---

What I like about this version is the idea of defining each $t_{j}$ as an equivalence class, which gets rid of this weird "$t_{j}$ is a symbol representing the $j^\text{th}$-smallest element of a set" formulation. On the other hand - and this is my biggest issue here - is this equivalence relation well-defined? The statement $j_{1}=j_{2}$ makes sense while we're talking about the variables $c_{j_{1}}^{C_{1}}$ and $c_{j_{2}}^{C_{2}}$; but I'm somewhat inclined towards looking at them as their values, i.e. the actual elements of the set $[\;n\;]$, at which point they lose their information about which index $j$ and subset $C$ they are associated with... Which interpretation is the correct one here?

Here's an alternative version for this definition:

---

**Definition Ver. 2:** Consider the set $$\mathcal{T} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{3}\left\{ t_{j}\right\}.$$
For a given set $C \in \mathcal{C}$, identify every element $c^{C}_{j}$ of $C$ with the element $t_{j}$ of $\mathcal{T}$ via the isomorphism $\tau_{C}:\mathcal{T}\rightarrow C$, $\tau_{C}:t_{j}\mapsto c^{C}_{j}.$

---

Using isomorphisms kind of makes more sense to me. On the other hand, now I'm stuck with my elements $t_{j}$ of $\mathcal{T}$ just being symbols without any further meaning to begin with. Furthermore, it seems like a strange construction to identify elements $t_{j}$ and $c^{C}_{j}$ by matching their indices $j$ - is it even clear when writing it like this? And is it legitimate to define $\mathcal{T}$ and $\tau_{C}$ together in one breath like that? (I could separate the definitions, but that makes the introduction of the object $\mathcal{T}$ even less understandable...)

Any help to clarify this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I find your proposed definitions a bit difficult to parse. I think, however, that the following may be close to what you're looking for:

We start by strengthening your initial observation, that each of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ (thought of as linear orders) are "the same." In fact, they're all the same **in a unique way**. Precisely, for any two three-element linear orderings $L_1,L_2$ there is a unique isomorphism $L_1\cong L_2$. This uniqueness is crucial: it lets us unambiguously talk about "$L_1$'s version of $x$" when $x$ is in $L_2$.

Thinking in terms of the "$L_1$'s version of $x$"-language, and generalizing to arbitrary structures since we don't really need to talk about linear orderings specifically **(for your specific example, see below)**, this sets up the following idea. Suppose we have a set $\mathcal{X}$ of structures such that for any $A,B\in\mathcal{X}$ there is a unique isomorphism $A\cong B$. Let $$\mathfrak{X}=\{\langle A,a\rangle: A\in \mathcal{X}, a\in A\}$$ be the set of "labelled elements" of elements of $\mathcal{X}$. We get an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathfrak{X}$ given by $$\langle A,a\rangle\sim \langle B,b\rangle\iff f_{A,B}(a)=b$$ where $f_{A,B}$ is the unique isomorphism $A\cong B$. We can then naturally view $\mathfrak{X}/\sim$ as a structure of the same type as the elements of $\mathcal{X}$ - and in fact we'll have $\mathfrak{X}/\sim$ be uniquely isomorphic to each element of $\mathcal{X}$ as expected.

---

In your specific example, here's what the above approach amounts to:

- $\mathfrak{X}$ has $3\cdot{n\choose 3}$ elements, including $\langle\{1,2,3\}, 2\rangle$ and $\langle \{2,3,4\},2\rangle$.
- The equivalence relation $\sim$ identifies $\langle A,a\rangle$ and $\langle B,b\rangle$ when $a$ occupies the same "place" in $A$ that $b$ does in $B$. So for example we have $$\langle \{1,2,3\},2\rangle\sim \langle \{1,2,4\},2\rangle$$ but $$\langle \{1,2,3\},2\rangle\not\sim \langle \{2,3,4\},2\rangle$$ (in the latter case, "$2$" is the second element of $\{1,2,3\}$ but the first element of $\{2,3,4\}$: the unique isomorphism between those two three-element linear orders sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, and $3$ to $4$).
- There are, as desired, exactly three $\sim$-classes of elements of $\mathfrak{X}$. So $\mathfrak{X}/\sim$ is a set with three elements, each of which is itself a set of $n\choose 3$ elements, each of which is itself an ordered pair, the first coordinate of which is a three element subset of $[n]$ and the second coordinate of which is an element of that subset. Whew!
- The **set** $\mathfrak{X}/\sim$ can be turned into a **linear order** in a natural way: we set $$[\langle A,a\rangle]_\sim \le [\langle B,b\rangle]_\sim$$ iff we have $f_{A,B}(a)\le_Bb$, where

  - $f_{A,B}$ is the unique isomorphism from $A$ to $B$, and
  - "$\le_B$" means "$\le$ in the sense of $B$" (which here is really just "$\le$," I'm using the more complicated notation to emphasize that we could be playing with very different $A$s and $B$s but things would still work).

  Of course we need to show that this $(i)$ is well-defined and $(ii)$ actually satisfies the linear order axioms, but this isn't hard.

---

Let me end by saying a bit about the importance of the **uniqueness** which I mentioned in the second paragraph and used crucially in defining $\sim$.

Suppose I have two structures $A$ and $B$ which are isomorphic but not *uniquely* isomorphic. For example, maybe $A$ is the linear ordering consisting of the rationals and $B$ is the linear ordering consisting of the dyadic rationals. [It turns out that these are isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method#Application_to_densely_ordered_sets), although that's not at all obvious. Now my question is:

> What's $B$'s version of $1\over 3$?

The point is that there are **lots** of ways to define an isomorphism between $A$ and $B$. In fact, there are as many as possible in a precise sense: a countable dense linear order is **homogeneous**. This prevents us from translating from one structure to the other in an unambiguous way.

We may still have some clever way of choosing a particular isomorphism between two structures according to some other special criteria, but if there are multiple isomorphisms to choose from this will probably be difficult. So if you have a huge collection $\mathcal{X}$ of *non-uniquely*-isomorphic structures, your best bet is probably to just pick a specific element of $\mathcal{X}$ to work with rather than try to whip up an "unbiased" version.